# React not rendering new state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to learn the new React hooks. I have written a simple todolist that users can type in input to create a new todo, and click on the todo to remove it. However, it is not re-rendering after an todo item is removed.

Here is my code

```
import React, { useState, Fragment } from "react";

const Todo = () => {
  const [inputVal, setInput] = useState("");
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);
  const handleInput = e => {
    setInput(e.target.value);
  };
  const handleClick = () => {
    setList([...list, inputVal]);
    setInput("");
  };
  const handleDelete = index => {
    setList([...list.splice(index, 1)]);
    console.log(list);
  };
  const renderList = () =>
    list.map((item, index) => {
      return (
        <div key={index} onClick={() => handleDelete(index)}>
          {item}
        </div>
      );
    });
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div>
        <input value={inputVal} onChange={handleInput} />
        <button onClick={handleClick}>submit</button>
      </div>
      <ul>{renderList()}</ul>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default Todo;
```

Comment: You use the index as the key, so it doesn't understand which items are which. Also array.splice (used in the delete handler) returns the removed items and mutates the original list, I'm guessing this is not the intended behaviour?

Comment: when I console.log list it prints the updated list, but the rendering function is not updating.

Comment: The `console.log` prints the updated list because `list.splice()` directly mutates `list`. This is the root of the issue. It may seem counterintuitive now, but if your app was working correctly the `console.log` would print the old value, not the new. This is because React doesn't update state immediately, it's delayed slightly so that multiple state changes can be grouped together automatically by React. This means you can't rely on accessing updated state immediately after you update it. (This isn't an answer, just an explanation on why your console.log won't work the way you expect.)

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues here.

1. `array.splice` is mutating and returns the removed items.
   When you run

```js
setList([...list.splice(index, 1)]);
```

This removes one item from the object `list` and then calls `setList([removed_item])`.

You could replace this line with

```js
setList(list.slice(0, index).concat(list.slice(index + 1))
```

What is currently happening is that you are setting the state as the same object as before (but mutated), so it doesn't trigger a re-render.

2. You are not using `key` attributes correctly.  You can read the docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

> We don’t recommend using indexes for keys if the order of items may change. This can negatively impact performance and may cause issues with component state.

Your keys should uniquely identify the elements of the todo list, without reference to the list itself.  The text in the item is a good choice, except for the possible problem of non-uniqueness.

When you re-render the todo list, React uses the keys to decide which children to re-render.  If you use indexes as keys, and then remove the item at index 0, then the 0th child will not be told to update to the new 0th element because it still gets the same key.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the help.